# Wordpress Newspaper child theme loads CSS twice

Tags: php, css, wordpress, child-theming

I am using Wordpress with Newspaper theme (as a child theme). I've noticed that my custom CSS from the child theme is loaded twice.

I checked function.php, and I am wondering if the second function is the root of my problem?

```
if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array(  ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 1001 );

if ( !function_exists( 'child_theme_configurator_css' ) ):
    function child_theme_configurator_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_child', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent','td-theme','td-theme-demo-style' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_configurator_css' );
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit 1: I have found these two lines of code via site code inspector. Do you think this might be it?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='td-theme-css'  href='.../wp-content/themes/Newspaper-lesser-old-child/style.css?ver=8.1.1504096948' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='chld_thm_cfg_child-css'  href='.../wp-content/themes/Newspaper-lesser-old-child/style.css?ver=8.1.1504096948' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Comment: Its not being loaded by the code you posted, so it must be getting loaded elsewhere. We have no way of knowing where without seeing the rest of your code, so you'll have to try debugging your site to find it.

Comment: Alright - i have no idea, where should i look first. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've edited post. Do you think this two lines might be it? And what to do with it?

Comment: Yes, its the 2 lines that are including the same stylesheet that are loading it twice! Your code is including one of them but I don't know where the other is coming from without seeing the enqueuing code from the parent theme. I've put together an answer below with some possible solutions - let me know if you have any questions or more info to add. Or if the answer helps with your problem, you can accept it so your question gets marked as resolved on the site, and other users with similar problems will know it could be helpful to them also. And it will also give us both rep points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see that the stylesheet is being included twice with different ids...:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='td-theme-css'  
      href='.../wp-content/themes/Newspaper-lesser-old-child/style.css?ver=8.1.1504096948' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='chld_thm_cfg_child-css'  
      href='.../wp-content/themes/Newspaper-lesser-old-child/style.css?ver=8.1.1504096948' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

...so we can use the ids `td-theme` and `chld_thm_cfg_child` to locate the problem.

You need to look at the functions called in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action in your functions.php in both your parent and child themes.

You've already found where your stylesheets are being enqueued in your child theme, and can see from the id that its being loaded by the following code from your child functions.php:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'child_theme_configurator_css' ) ):
    function child_theme_configurator_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_child', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent','td-theme','td-theme-demo-style' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_configurator_css' );
```

So now we need to track down the other instance. This is where the difficulty is 
because you haven't included the enqueuing code from the parent.

**Potential Causes & Solutions:**

1. **The parent theme is using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`**

As far as I can tell, the id `td-theme` comes from the Newspaper theme. This suggests that it is using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()` to load the stylesheet.

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri` loads the stylesheet from the active theme's folder, so if a child of that theme is active, then it will load the child stylesheet instead of its own.

If its being loaded by the parent theme already, you don't need to load it again in the child theme so remove the code that loads the child stylesheet again in the child functions.php

*There are other potential causes of this issue, but they don't appear to apply here. However I'll include them just in case your question doesn't have all the enqueuing functions, and also for anyone else who might have similar problems.*

2. **If your child theme is including it instead of the parent theme**

A child theme could be incorrectly trying to load the parent stylesheet as well as the child one. In that case, I'd expect to see something like this in your child's function.php:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'td-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',  
                  array(), $version);
wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',  
                  array(), $version);
```

In your case, this doesn't appear to be the problem, because you are using a different id ("chld_thm_cfg_parent") to load the parent stylesheet.

If this *was* the case, to fix it you should use `get_template_directory_uri` for the parent stylesheet and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` for the child, e.g.:

```
/* load parent stylesheet from parent theme folder with get_template_directory_uri */
wp_enqueue_style( "td-theme", get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' , 
                  array(), $version);

/* load child stylesheet from child theme folder withget_stylesheet_directory_uri
   Note: we include the parent's id in the dependencies array so it gets loaded first */ 
wp_enqueue_style( "chld_thm_cfg_child", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
                  array("parent-id"), $version);
```

(Note that this could cause the parent theme to be included twice, depending on how its included in the parent theme - but again without seeing the actual code, it's difficult to know exactly).

Comment: Hello, thank you for great answer! I've managed it with commenting the part of enquening in child funcion.php. It seems okey now.
But strange thing - i can't find, where the parent theme loads this td-theme css. I will probably go through whole template folder to find it, because i am curious.
Again, thanks for help.

Comment: @p31r Glad I could help! It sounds like your parent theme is loading the child stylesheet using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`, in that case. Yes it can be annoying when you can't find something like that, even if its working anyway! Good luck finding it :)